# Visual Studio 2010: Where are the Project Sub Folders

Tags: visual-studio-2010, include, directory

I am really new to visual studio (2010 professional) and she is not being nice at all.

In my solutions explorer (for an empty project) I see these 4 folders (or filters!), where are they physically located?

I created a header file under the "Header Files" folder but I got the classic "cannot open include file..."!

Even if I create a folder it does not show up physically!

What do I do? Please help!

Avishek

Comment: A filter is not a folder, it is merely meant to organize the files in your project in a logical way.  Like keeping resources, header files and source code files separate.  The only thing that's obvious is that you are not doing it right, but you left no breadcrumbs to help us help you.  Get ahead by using a better project template, like Win32 Console.

Comment: Thanks Hans, that clears the filter-folder confusion!

Comment: I am using the Win32 console template. I finally got the header file to get included by specifying the physical project folder again under the configuration properties, which I did not expect.